# Angular JS- ui.bootstrap.collapse not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular-ui Bootstrap for my application. I am trying to use the collapse property of angular-ui bootstrap.

I am doing the same as shown in the example on this [site](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) in the collapse part. But i am not getting what is wrong i am doing in my code that this is not working properly.

This is the snippet from my code

```
<h1>Your Connections</h1><a href="" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" class="button-link">Invite your friend to join you</a>
            <div collapse="isCollapsed">
                <button style="float:right; margin-right: 4px; margin-top: 5px; background-color: #8AA8BD; height: 30px" ng-click="sendInvite()">Send</button>
                <input type="text" class="well well-sm" style="float: right">
            </div>
```

While running this code it is giving the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at e (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js:8)
at Object.fn (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js:8)
at Object.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:9831)
at Object.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:10039)
at angular.js:1127
at Object.invoke (angular.js:3123)
at doBootstrap (angular.js:1125)
at bootstrap (angular.js:1140)
at angularInit (angular.js:1091)
at angular.js:17898(anonymous function) @ angular.js:7818$get @ angular.js:5601$get.Scope.$digest @ angular.js:9843$get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js:10039(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1127invoke @ angular.js:3123doBootstrap @ angular.js:1125bootstrap @ angular.js:1140angularInit @ angular.js:1091(anonymous function) @ angular.js:17898trigger @ angular.js:1990(anonymous function) @ angular.js:2246forEach @ angular.js:196eventHandler @ angular.js:2245
```

as well as the follwing error

```
TypeError: fn is not a function
at angular.js:11316
at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:3457)
at angular.js:3751
```

Please help me get the wrong i am doing in the code.
Any help will be appreciated.... Thanks.

Comment: The problem may be outside of the code snippet you are showing. Do you have your module and controller setup properly and ng-app and ng-controller set in the html? Also do you use the isCollapsed variable anywhere else and are you initializing it in your controller? 
It is working in this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/6iNCnnZPXp1OpBsitmig

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Sapy. I have done exactly the same as is given in the plunker. Also i have i have set up my ng-app and ng-controller properly in my html. But i am not getting what is wrong in the code.

Comment: Well using a link href="" may be causing a page reload every time you click it. Try using a button `<button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"> CLICK HERE </button>` 
Also do you have a bunch of other code in your project? The error may be generated someplace else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution to my question.
The problem was that i was using an older version of Angular JS(version 1.2.X).
The UI bootstrap does not support this version. As soon as i updated my project with the latest version of Angular JS(version 1.4.3) the code start to work for me.

**NOTE**:- Requires version 1.3.X at least to make Angular UI-Bootstrap work for your code.